# How to add elements in List when used Arrays.asList()

Tags: java, list

We cannot perform `<Collection>.add` or `<Collection>.addAll` operation on collections we have obtained from `Arrays.asList` .. only remove operation is permitted.

So What if I come across a scenario where I require to add new Element in `List` without deleting previous elements in `List`?. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why can't you add? `asList` returns a `new ArrayList`. Oh, it's not the same `ArrayList`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Lists returned by Arrays.asList are backed by the array passed in, and are unmodifiable.  From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) (emphasis added), "Returns a ***fixed-size list*** backed by the specified array. (Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.) This method acts as bridge between array-based and collection-based APIs, in combination with Collection.toArray(). The returned list is serializable and implements RandomAccess."

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Had not noticed it was `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Well, the javadoc only guarantees that's it's a fixed size list, though yes, it does seem that's it's an `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList`.  `java.util.ArrayLists`, of course, are, in general, modifiable.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` extends `AbstractList` which throws `UnsupportedOperationException()` for some of the methods.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Right;  my point is that _the javadoc_ doesn't guarantee that you'll get a `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` back, just that you'll get a fixed size `List` (so it makes sense that it throws an `UnsupportedOperationException` when attempts are made to change its size).  However, `java.util.ArrayList` (not the `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList`) is a "resizable-array implementation of the List interface", according to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Comment: @prafulsurve The remove operation isn't permitted either;  the list returned by Arrays.asList is fixed in size.  A simple test will confirm that you can neither add elements to nor remove elements from the list.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Create a new `ArrayList` using the constructor:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("a", "b"));
```

Comment: or Stream.of("a", "b", "c").collect(Collectors.toList())

Answer (score 15):

One way is to construct a new `ArrayList`:

```
List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>(Arrays.asList(...));
```

Having done that, you can modify `list` as you please.

Answer (score 6):

Arrays.asList(),generates a list which is actually backed by an array and it is an array which is morphed as a list. You can use it as a list but you can't do certain operations on it such as adding new elements. So the best option is to pass it to a constructor of another list obj like this:

```
List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>(Arrays.asList(...));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get around the intermediate `ArrayList` with Java8 streams:

```
    Integer[] array = {1, 2, 3};
    List<Integer> list = Streams.concat(Arrays.stream(array),
                                        Stream.of(4)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This should be pretty efficient as it can just iterate over the array and also pre-allocate the target list. It may or may not be better for large arrays. As always, if it matters you have to measure.

Answer (score 3):

The Constructor for a Collection, such as the ArrayList, in the following example, will take the array as a list and construct a new instance with the elements of that list.

```
List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>(Arrays.asList(...));
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(java.util.Collection)

Answer (score 3):

These days the streams API can easily get you an `ArrayList` in a concise and functional manner:

```
Stream.of("str1", "str2").collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Of course this also has the flexibility to transform using mappings. For example, while writing unit tests for Spring security code it was convenient to write the following:

```
Stream.of("ROLE_1", "ROLE_2").map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

The list returned by `Collectors.toList` is an `ArrayList` and may be modified as required by your code.

Answer (score 0):

> Arrays.asList()

generates an unmodifiable list on object creation. You can use the below code.

```
List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList(...));
```

This convert allows the list to add and remove objects. I have only tested in java 8.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Object> MyObjectList = new ArrayList<>();
Arrays.asList(params[1]).forEach((item)-> {
    MyObjectList.add(item);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! 
However, you should add a few comments to your answer to explain what advantage your solution has over the accepted answer, or what other new circumstances make your solution more attractive.